# Disable default settings like "wordBasedSuggestions" from an Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension for VSCode which is supplying completion items but there are word suggestions among them.

I know you can in your User/Workspace settings disable `editor.wordBasedSuggestions` but are there a way to this from an extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, extensions can change the default value of settings by contributing `configurationDefaults` in `package.json`:

```json
"contributes": {
    "configurationDefaults": {
        "[lang]": {
            "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
        }
    }
}
```

Where `lang` is the ID of the language in question.

Answer (score 1):

This can now be done in a general **non-language-specific** method.   See [release notes: change configuration defaults](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#configuration-defaults-overrides).

> ##### Configuration Defaults Overrides
>
> You can now override defaults of other registered configurations
> through `configurationDefaults` contribution point in `package.json`.
> For example, the following snippet overrides the default behavior of
> `files.autoSave` setting to auto save files on focus change.

```
"contributes": {
  "configurationDefaults": {                 // applies to all languages
      "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange"
  }
}
```

> Note: Configurations with application or machine scopes cannot be
> overridden.