# Contribute language association from extensions in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I contribute a language association from an extension in VSCode?

In `settings.json` it would've looked like this:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.something": "markdown"
}
```

I know that it's possible to use `vscode.languages.setTextDocumentLanguage`. But that seems excessive to do every time the `activeEditor` changes, and it's one more event listener.

Using the API to write into user settings doesn't seem right either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, extensions can contribute settings [via `configurationDefaults`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550536/disable-wordbasedsuggestions-from-an-extension/53971423#53971423). However, I don't think this works for the `files.associations` setting.

What you can do instead is contribute a new file extension for the `markdown` language:

```json
"contributes": {
    "languages": [
        {
            "id": "markdown",
            "extensions": [
                "something"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This won't replace the previous registration of the `markdown` language, instead it will be merged with it.

Comment: That sounds like a recipe for conflicts as it does not allow you to set file patterns for matching documents.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change to your package.json, I figured it out by studying an existing extension.

You must add **.** before something

Also see :
[How can I write a vsc snippets extension for a language that is not listed on visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677168/how-can-i-write-a-vsc-snippets-extension-for-a-language-that-is-not-listed-on-vi)

```
"contributes": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "markdown",
        "extensions": [
          ".something"
        ],
      }
    ]
}
```