# How to use editor.maxTokenizationLineLength in a VS Code language extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to use "editor.maxTokenizationLineLength" in a vscode language extension or similar implementations.

The situation is that I have my own language type. I want to have a limitation of the line length, because whenever a linebreak occurs in the expected value, the colored highlight will be lost, removing so the warning for the user.

Comment: It might be possible via `configurationDefaults`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550536/disable-wordbasedsuggestions-from-an-extension/53971423#53971423 for instance. I'm not sure if `maxTokenizationLineLength` is available as a language-specific setting though.

Comment: @Gama11, thanks for the useful tip, but maxTokenizationLineLength does not work for a language extension.

Comment: @Gama11 I finally use "editor.rulers": [value], at least this could give an editor area warning.

Comment: I tried to fix the question text to conform to SO's standards, but I'm not 100% sure I found the correct wording. Don't hesitate to fix further if I didn't catch the original problem correctly.

Answer (score 15):

In `Visual Studio Code` go to `File--> Preferences--> Setting` and search for `Max`, you will find `Max Tokenization Length`. Change values there.